# How to find the last updated value of GPS in Cache in android

Tags: android, gps

### What i have:

I get the last updated value from the GPS cache as below

```
Location location;

location = appLocationService.getLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
if(location!=null){
    latitude=location.getLatitude();
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
}
```

### What I am trying to do:

1. How can I find out the last updated cache in GPS is not more than an
   hour ago
2. How can I find out the last updated cache in GPS is not more than a
   day ago

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Location class has a method named `getTime()` which gives you the time of when the GpsLocation Received , so comparing it with current Time will give you the comparison if the cashed location is outdated or not.